# Does Node.js "new Socket" create a Unix file socket?

Tags: file, sockets, unix, node.js, file-descriptor

I've been working with node.js for the past couple of weeks and I need to implement the FAST-CGI protocol.
The problem is that when I create a UNIX socket (via "new Socket") I need to get the filename, or file descriptor. But socket.fd is null (default parameter).

My question is: Does "new Socket" creates a operating system socket object file, and if so, how can I get the Socket File Descriptor or File Name?

I'm not sure if this is how I should create a Socket, but here is the case: 

node:

```
var net = require(net)
var socket = new net.Socket()
console.log(socket);

{
 bufferSize: 0,
 fd:null,
 type: null,
 allowHalfOpen: false,
 _writeImpl: [Function],
 _readImpl: [Function],
 _shutdownImpl: [Function]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly, socket.fd is empty until you actually do socket.connect() ;)

Comment: Oohhh.... So the actual system socket is created when connect is called.But when i call socket.connect('/tmp/file.sock') it gives me (Error: ENOENT, No such file or directory)... Should I create the file before ? or what should I do ?

Comment: Yes, you should. Also, as I noted in my answer below, FD can be given when creating new socket: new net.Socket({fd : '/tmp/file.sock'})

Comment: It turns out, that you should only specify the existing file descriptor of socket, and it should be a number (fd:NaN)... So how do I create the file ? Should I use fs.open ???

Comment: Yeah, fs.open is the way. I appended the code to my answer below. Works for me on Ubuntu (with node 0.4.11)

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!! You saved me from a lot of trouble!!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Well when you connect a socket, socket.fd is not null, at least not in my case, so provide an example case please.

Note that you can also specify existing file descriptor [at socket creation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.7/api/net.html#new_net.Socket).

**Edit:**

```
var net = require('net'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    sock;

// Create socket file
fs.open('/tmp/node.test.sock', 'w+', function(err, fdesc){
    if (err || !fdesc) {
        throw 'Error: ' + (err || 'No fdesc');
    }

    // Create socket
    sock = new net.Socket({ fd : fdesc });
    console.log(sock);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, it says "Unsupported fd type: FILE". :(